# Creating a simple array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$page=3;

$i=1;

    while($i<=$pages) {
      $urls .= "'"."http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=" . $i ."',";
      $i++;
    }
```

What I need to create is this array:

```
$data = array('http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=1','http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=2','http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=3');
```

How can I produce an array from the `while` loop?

Comment: *(reference)* http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$page=3;

$i=1;
$url=array();

while($i<=$pages) {
    $urls[]="http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=".$i ;
    $i++;
}

echo("<pre>".print_r($url,true)."</pre>");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$urls = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
    $urls[] = "http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=$x";
}
```

`.` is for concatenating strings.
`[]` is for accessing arrays.
`[] =` pushes a value onto the end of an array (automatically creates a new element in the array and assigns to it).

Comment: +1, however it would be better to retain the $pages variable and use that in the for loop condition

Comment: Ain't it supposed to assign an index to the array $urls[$x] = "http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=$x";

Comment: @Jeremy no, danits example doesn't suggest this, $url[] will auto assign a key.

Comment: @Jeremy, the index is not required, the $urls[] syntax is equivalent to array_push($urls, ....)

Comment: If the `$page` value is needed any further it's easy enough to rewrite the loop accordingly, I'll leave that as an exercise to the OP. :)

Comment: I think you need $x inside the string , not $i ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$page=3;
$i=1;    
$data = array();
while($i <= $page) {
    $data[] = "http://twitter.com/favorites.xml?page=" . $i++;
}
```

Comment: Your url value isn't correct, lose the quotes at each end and the comma, he just wants the URL.